# Can't get near Users by my location with Firebase (GeoFire) and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

I want to get all Users near by my own Location.

I wrote following code in the location Manager didUpdateLocation function.

```
First I grabbed my own location as a CCLocationCoridnate2D.
if let location = locations.last{ let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
```

Than I made a query to get all users near by my location.

```
let geofireRef = Database.database().reference()
                let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
            
            
            
            
            
            geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude), forKey: "test")
          
         
            let centerQuery = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            let circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: centerQuery, withRadius: 5)

            var queryHandle = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
               print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
                
                
                
            })
```

If I now want to replace "test" with my actual user (userdocid) it won't work.

How I grab my User:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "x")
                            .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
                                if err != nil {
                                    print("Failed")
                                    return
                                }
let  userdocid = querySnapshot!.documents[0].documentID
```

The App is crashing because of empty NSArray.

Thank you in advance
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer depends on how you're user data is stored but if you're storing users with their documentId as the users uid then just

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid //should safe unwrap that optional
```

then

```
geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(..., forKey: uid)
```

however, if you want to get it as you're doing in the question

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
let usersCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                               .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
                        
usersCollection.getDocument(completion: { documentSnapshot, error in
    if let err = error {
         print(err.localizedDescription)
         return
     }

     guard let docs = documentSnapshot?.documents else { return }

     let thisUserUid = docs[0].documentID
     print(thisUserUid)
})
```

But again, that's a bit redundant as it wound indicate storing the uid in both the documentId as well as a child field, which is unnecessary:

```
users
  uid_0 //the documentId
     name: "Users name"
     uid: "uid_0" //not needed
```

The problem appers to be actually getting the center point - e.g. if it's not stored, then when read, it will be empty and you'll get that error.

So you have to store it to start with

```
geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: 37.7853889, longitude: -122.4056973), forKey: uid) { (error) in
  if (error != nil) {
    print("An error occured: \(error)")
  } else {
    print("Saved location successfully!")
  }
}
```

Once you successfully stored a center point (your location), and then retrieved it, then the actual query should be

```
let center = CLLocation(userLocation)
geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 20);
```

Oh, and a very important thing is the setLocation is asynchronous; it takes time for the server to store the data. You should really be working with the data within the closure

```
geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: 37.7853889, longitude: -122.4056973), forKey: uid) { (error) in
   // data is now valid so perform your query
}
```

Comment: but the question is how to grab users near by a distance and not how to grab users from the database

Comment: @Markus The issue was this *If I now want to replace "test" with my actual user (userdocid) it won't work.* because of this *The App is crashing because of empty NSArray.* so that has to be addressed first. We don't know where the app was crashing as that troubleshooting was not indicated in the question; so we are guessing at this point. See the updated answer as well.

Comment: @Markus I had hit save before I was done with the answer. I threw in some additional information which may help.

Comment: I don‘t want to set the location by my own. I want to use the CC Location manager. Thanks

Comment: So all inside the CC Location manager...grab my own location and than set it at this point

Comment: @Markus Not *your* own but the location of the user, and yes, if you store the location of the user using setLocation, you need to wait for that task to be completed before doing the query - that will only work within a closure following setLocation as it takes times for the data to be written; code is faster than the internet.

Comment: Can you edit it for the example? Dont know how to do this...with a global variable?

Comment: oh yes I got it...                                                                                            Key 'Optional("dk0cSiEspOPyyxfBkt02NlriQHK2")' entered the search area and is at location 'Optional(<+48.3xxxx,+11.50xxxx> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 22.02.21, 22:11:37 Central European Standard Time)'
Key 'Optional("mZesahDqZrc2lFYfxHk2TwCNp892")' entered the search area and is at location 'Optional(<+48.3xxxx,+11.5xxxx>
Key 'Optional("dk0cSiEspOPyyxfBkt02NlriQHK2")' entered the search area and is at location 'Optional(<+48.3xxxxx,+11xxxxx>

Comment: How can I get a pin on the new user location?

Comment: @Markus that's a different question and also covered in the docs. Check that first and if you get stuck, ask a separate question as here on SO we like to keep it one question per question. If my answer helped, please accept it so it can help others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340656/set-a-pin-if-geofire-find-a-person-in-your-region