# Set a Pin if GeoFire find a Person in your region

Tags: swift, firebase, geofire

i have got the Persons near my region in GeoFire. (Firebase)

Now I want to set for each Person a pin.

I wrote the whole code in the CL Location Manager function.
See the topic: [Can't get near Users by my location with Firebase (GeoFire) and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322010/cant-get-near-users-by-my-location-with-firebase-geofire-and-swift/66322340?noredirect=1#comment117255029_66322340)

Now my idea was this:

```
  var queryHandle = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
          print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
        let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        newPin.coordinate = location.coordinate
        self.MapView.addAnnotation(newPin)     
}
```

For each User there should be a pin. I wrote this code, which is not working at all:

```
 var queryHandle = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        annotation.coordinate = coord
        annotation.title = userID
        self.MapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    })
```

Comment: This `self.MapView` looks a little odd. Typically Capitals are used for Class and Structure names and vars are lowercased like `let myMapVIew = ...`. Could be nothing but take a look.

Comment: The second piece of code is not working because you're creating an empty coord with `let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D()`. You need to get the key and location (coord) that's passed into the query and use that to create your annotation pin locations.

Comment: This is circle query????

Comment: That's the code you wrote in your question so I assume so - that's generally how geofire works (see the docs)

Comment: But don‘t work.

Comment: Please read comments instead of just telling us something doesn't work. As I said in my above comment, it doesn't work because the code is not correct. You're creating an empty coord and then trying to put it on the map - which won't work. You need to create a coord based on the CLLLocation data passed into the query's closure. Again, I strongly encourage you to read the documentation because that's covered with an example.

Comment: so what do I have to edit at let coord = CLLLocationCordinate2D()? I DONT KNOW ANYMORE WHAT TO DO AND I READ THE DOC SEVERIAL TIMES

Comment: First, read the [CLLocation Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation) to see the API for how location services work. Then check out the specific documentation on [CLLocationCoordinate2D](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationcoordinate2d) to see how to initialize it. There are also some great [Q&A's](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+CLLocationCoordinate2D) here on SO with examples. You can also see this [great tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5247-core-location-tutorial-for-ios-tracking-visited-locations).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First, get the users location

```
let center = CLLocation(latitude: users_lat, longitude: users_long)
```

then define a radius around that center

```
var circleQuery = geoFire.query(at: center, withRadius: .60) //600 meters
```

Then to get all of the other users within that circle, perform a query

```
self.queryHandle = circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key: String?, location: CLLocation?) in
   print("Key '\(key)' entered the search area and is at location '\(location)'")
})
```

Keeping in mind that Key entered events will be fired for all keys initially matching the query as well as any time afterwards that a key enters the query

Don't forget to define queryHandle as a class var.

Also, remember to point geoFire to your firebase when initting

```
let geofireRef = Database.database().reference()
let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireRef)
```

To add pins to the map, just do this for each pin - just like the code in your question

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(each users location)
annotation.coordinate = coord
annotation.title = "some user name"
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: Thank you very much...but i had this. The question is how to get the pins for each user...

Comment: @Markus I think I mentioned it in the answer **Key entered events will be fired for all keys initially matching the query** and that includes the key and location so you can then generate a pin.

Comment: And that would be my question :D I have already managed to get all users within a 20 mile radius. But these users have no pin yet but only a print statement....

Comment: @Markus Are you asking to how to add a pin to the map in general? There are a significant number of examples here on SO and Apple Documentation [adding annotations to a map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview) is a good read. If you're updating pins as users mode, you can simply store the users coords in an array and loop over that when there's an update - dont forget to remove the old pins so you dont duplicate them. The code in your question is correct for adding a pin, so what's the issue?

Comment: Sorry but i dont know how to push every Geofire Point into an array...

Comment: @Markus You're adding a single pin in the code in your question - do the same for the rest of the users you have. You said you already have all uses within a 20 mile radius - add the pins for them to the same array.

Comment: so I have var myArray[ ] = [ "oneuser"] than I make myVar.append() and what should I write in the ()?

Comment: @Markus Not sure what that code is but the code in your question shows this `self.MapView.addAnnotation(newPin)` and that adds a pin to your mapView.

Comment: i don´t understand what you mean with the pin. You have this code with: let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(each users location)
annotation.coordinate = coord
annotation.title = "some user name"
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation) and then you say this code self.MapView.addAnnotation(newPin)

Comment: I get the print statement, if somebody come in my area but not a pin.....

Comment: @Markus I don't understand what you're asking. I am referring the question you posted with YOUR code in it. If you want to add pins to a map the [MKMapView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview) shows how - you can also use the code in my answer (which came from the Apple documentation). There are also a lot of [tutorials](https://www.devfright.com/mkpointannotation-tutorial/) available as well as tons of [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5DMKMapView) here on SO. My answer shows how to add a pin... what is the question?

Comment: I know how to add a Pin. The question ist how to add a Pin WITH THE USERS AROUND MY LOCATION (20 Miles for example)

Comment: @Markus ok. Let's think through this. Your comment above says **I have already managed to get all users within a 20 mile radius** so you know the users and their locations. You now need to add one for each user. Your following comment says **I know how to add a Pin**. So if you know how to add a pin, and you have 20 users and their locations, what's preventing you from adding one for each of the 20 users?

Comment: yes ok that was now maybe a bit arrogant...so I hope we are now on the same denominator. What I wanted with this SO Topic is that I set a pin for each user that I have in the query. So that I see who where all uses the app. This question does not yet exist on SO with reference to Firebase / GeoFire.

Comment: Again, you said you know how to add a pin so it's not clear what's preventing you from adding 20 pins for 20 users. The code in my answer will do it for one user so just do the same thing for each user.

Comment: yes and this is the thing I don't know and why I created the topic........I don't know how to get it. A foor loop for each user at my database???

Comment: @Markus Sure. You can loop over users if you want. You can just do it for each user as they are returned in the query. From my answer **Keeping in mind that Key entered events will be fired for all keys initially matching the query**. You should really read the [geofire documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc) as it has specific examples of how to use it - for example keyEntered is fired for each key that enters the circleQuery. See [this section](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#receiving-events-for-geo-queries)

Comment: is it possible to edit your post for it? Don't really get it....

Comment: my idea was this.....  let users = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                let user = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("uid")
                
                for user in users {
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
                    annotation.coordinate = coord
                    annotation.title = "some user name"
                    self.MapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }

Comment: @Markus I am not sure what else to add. My answer contains the exact code needed to add the annotation and it's pretty close to the code in your question. I am not sure what else I can to help since I already gave you the required code. I also feel that you've not seen that part of the geofire documentation since there's a specific example showing how to use it. If you did read it, please update your question what the code you've attempted so we can see where you're at (no code in comments please)

Comment: Ok...maybe I have to start from beginning. I can set my location for oneuser. Then I make the database query with Firebase/GeoFire to get the Users near by my location. this works!! NOW I WANT TO GET THOSE USERS WHO ARE IN MY QUERY, TO BE ADDED AS A PIN IN MY APP. I read all the docs about GeoFire, but there is no forEach example.

Comment: @Markus The only reason to use a forEach is if you storing your users in an array and want to iterate over them. You don't have to do that - see the the [GeoFire Documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#receiving-events-for-geo-queries) (again) where it says **Key entered events will be fired for all keys initially matching the query**. I mentioned that in my answer as well as above. That means the code in the closure will execute for each matching key, which is where you put the code to add the pin. Otherwise remove the pin with Key Exited events.

Comment: added a new comment with the code. this is what you mean? thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: @Markus You added code as an answer - don't do that unless it IS the answer or the moderators will delete it. You should update the QUESTION with additional information. You need to create a coord from the passed in CLLOCATION

Comment: sorry I am new in Stackoverflow. Also I am very new at Swift. What do you mean? Maybe you can update your comment

Comment: @Markus See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Why are answers deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Answers should be posted that actually answer the question, not additional information to the question. If you want to ask 'is this code correct', post it IN the question as additional information. If it works and correctly solves the problem *then* post it as an answer so it can help others.